# Masonry различная ширина колонок

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, masonry

[image: Нужно получить структуру плиток как на изображении]

Необходимо получить структуру плиток как на изображении, используя библиотеку masonry.

Так же необходимо чтобы порядок плиток не нарушался.

Проблема в том, что не получается сделать такую структуру, как на изображении. Если я указываю размеры плиток 30% 40% 30%, они перестраиваются в неверном порядке. Но если указать 25% 50% 25%, то плитки становятся нужным образом.

css

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

        body { font-family: sans-serif; }

        /* ---- grid ---- */

        .grid {
            margin: 0 !important;
            background: #EEE;
        }

        /* clearfix */
        .grid:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* ---- grid-item ---- */

        .grid-sizer,
        .grid-item {
            width: 30%;
        }

        .grid-item {
            height: 120px;
            float: left;
            background: #D26;
            border: 2px solid #333;
            border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .grid-item--width2 { 
            width:  40%; 
            height: 240px; 
        }
```

html

```
<div class="grid">
          <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

          <div class="grid-item"></div>
          <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"></div>

          <div class="grid-item"></div>
          <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"></div>

          <div class="grid-item"></div>
          <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"></div>

        </div>
```

js

```
 $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: 0, //Отключить отступы
    percentPosition: true, //Позиционирование в процентах
    horizontalOrder: true // горизонтальный порядок плиток (по порядку)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

На скорую руку. А почему бы не так?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

        body { font-family: sans-serif; }

        /* ---- grid ---- */

        .grid {
            margin: 0 !important;
            background: #EEE;
        }

        /* clearfix */
        .grid:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer{

}

.grid-item {
  float:left; 
  width:  30%; 
  height: 120px;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-item--width2 { 
  float: left;
  width:  40%; 
  float: center;
  height: 240px; 
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.item{
  height: 33%;

}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item">1.1</div>
    <div class="item">1.2</div>
    <div class="item">1.3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item--width2">
    <div class="item">21</div>
    <div class="item">22</div>
    <div class="item">23</div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item">31</div>
    <div class="item">32</div>
    <div class="item">33</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну с колонками то понятно что работать будет) , просто интересно почему библиотека не работает правильно